# How to solve "An unhandled exception occured" with a Google Maps Android App? -Xamarin

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I made an app that runs google maps and then takes your input to find the desired place. Every time I run it through the emulator though it pops up with the message "An unhandled exception occurred". I don't know how to over come this and if this is a problem with the emulator or something wrong with my code?

This is my Main Activity:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Locations;
using System.Linq;
using Android.Util;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SafeandSound
{
[Activity(Label = "SafeandSound", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);


        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        SetUpMap();
    }
    private void SetUpMap()
    {
        if (mMap == null)
        {
            FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.map);
        }
    }

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mMap = googleMap;

    }
    // Button to Search for Address//
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task onMapSearchAsync(View view)
    {
        EditText gotAddress = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.searchText);
        string addressnew = gotAddress.Text;
        if (!Geocoder.IsPresent)
        {
            Log.Error("SO", "Geocoder is not present");
        }
        else
        {
            var geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            var retry = 0;
            do
            {
                var addressList = await geocoder.GetFromLocationNameAsync(addressnew, 5);
                if (addressList.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var address in addressList)
                    {
                        Log.Debug("SO", $"{address.Latitude}:{address.Longitude} - {address.FeatureName} : {address.GetAddressLine(0)} : {address.GetAddressLine(1)}");
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.Latitude, address.Longitude);
                        CameraPosition.Builder builder = CameraPosition.InvokeBuilder();
                        builder.Target(latLng);
                        builder.Zoom(10);
                        CameraPosition cameraPosition = builder.Build();
                        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(cameraPosition);

                    }
                    break;
                }
                retry++;
                Log.Warn("SO", $"No addresses returned...., retrying in {retry * 2} secs");
                await Task.Delay(retry * 1000);
            } while (retry < 5);
        }

    }
}
}
```

And this is my Main code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/background_light">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/searchText"
        android:layout_width="303.5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:hint="Search Location..."
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:onClick="onMapSearch"
        android:text="Search" />
</LinearLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add your `Resource.Layout.Main` axml to your question.

Comment: @SushiHangover I tried adding it before but it wouldn't let me, now i fixed it

Comment: What is the `full exception` that you are getting as I am seeing a number of things that could be issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This assumes you are starting with a template-based Xamarin.Android project...

#### Add Google Maps:

Add the `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps` package to your project

#### Main.axml

Change your default `Main.axml` to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:id="@+id/searchText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Search Location..."/>
        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/search_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

#### MainActivty.cs:

Replace the entire MainActivity class with:

```
[Activity(Label = "Google Map and GeoCode Example", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity, IOnMapReadyCallback
{
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    EditText searchTextEdit;
    Geocoder geoCoder;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        var searchButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.search_button);
        searchButton.Click += SearchButtonClick;
        searchButton.Enabled &= Geocoder.IsPresent;

        searchTextEdit = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.searchText);
        searchTextEdit.Enabled &= Geocoder.IsPresent;

        var mapFragment = FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<MapFragment>(Resource.Id.map);
        mapFragment.GetMapAsync(this);
    }

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
        geoCoder = new Geocoder(this);
    }

    async void SearchButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                var addressList = await geoCoder.GetFromLocationNameAsync(searchTextEdit.Text, 10);
                for (int j = 0; j < addressList.Count(); j++)
                {
                    var address = addressList[j];
                    var latLng = new LatLng(address.Latitude, address.Longitude);
                    if (j == 0) // Move the map to the first address return
                    {
                        var cameraPosition = CameraPosition.InvokeBuilder()
                           .Target(latLng)
                           .Zoom(15)
                           .Build();
                        var cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(cameraPosition);
                        googleMap.MoveCamera(cameraUpdate);
                    }
                    var marker = new MarkerOptions(); // Add markers for all addresses found
                    marker.SetTitle($"{address.FeatureName}");
                    marker.SetPosition(latLng);
                    googleMap.AddMarker(marker);
                }
                if (addressList.Any()) { i = 99; break; }
                await Task.Delay(1000 * i);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) // Google Server timeouts will throw....
            {
                Log.Error("SO", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Google Map API key:

You will need a Google map API key assigned to this app:

```
http://console.developers.google.com/
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml

Once you obtain a key, add it to your project. Instead of manually modifying your `AndroidManifest.xml`, you can add an Assembly-level `MetaData` attribute.

Adding the following to your `Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: MetaData("com.google.android.geo.API_KEY", Value = "YourGoogleMapApiKeyGoesHere")]
```

#### Results on searching "Starbucks 98101":

[image]

Comment: I had the API KEY but it looked like my Main activity was messed up! Your code works thanks! Can you explain to me where mine was wrong? Just trying to learn this whole thing.

Comment: There were a few things, but I did not go line-lby-line, a big thing is you did not add `IOnMapReadyCallback` to your activity class and thus the map ready method is never called and thus your google map variable is never assigned...

Comment: Okay thanks for the input, new to the language and just trying to learn! Thanks for the help again